# Scala Sparksession not initialised properly in junit dataframe foreach

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, foreach

I have a spark 2.4 scala 2.11 code which does some work using a foreach over a dataframe. In unit tests I'm using a local sparksession object.
The issue is that- inside the foreach loop I'm trying to create and modify a dataframe using Seq todf method. For some wierd reason the spark session inside the loop is not being instantiated properly and I'm getting a null pointer exception in sqlcontext when trying to do the above said manipulation
Any ideas how can I ensure that the spark session object inside the loop is proper so that the unit test gets executed properly

Additional opinion
It seems spark has a connection to a file due to which it cannot be serialized, hence it fails in junit.

Comment: A Spark DF is an immutable structure. Share your code to see what are you trying to do

Comment: Something like creating dataframe from static vales. Seq(123,456).toDf